# Rewriting a folder name using .htaccess doesn't want to work

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am wondering, why folder renaming doesn't work. `RewriteRule ^pl/(.*) public/$1`

Let's say I have a URL like:

```
example.com/public/index.html
```

Now I want to rewrite the URL to

```
example.com/pl/index.html
```

`pl` is not a folder rather just a name!

The rest works fine. Why just that one rule doesn't work?

My **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^dekoracyjne.html$ decorative.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^pl/(.*) public/$1
RewriteRule ^dekoracyjne/(.*) decorative/$1
RewriteRule ^techniczne.html$ architectural.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^techniczne/(.*) architectural/$1
RewriteRule ^show.html/([-\w]+)$ show.php?id=${products:$1} [L]
RewriteRule ^p.html$ product_configurator.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^show_c\.html/([-*\w]+)$ show_c.php?cat=${catcolors:$1} [L]
RewriteRule ^(product_configurator)\.html/(\d+)&([-\w]+)$ $1.php?prometheus_id=$2&id=${products:$3} [L]
RewriteRule ^(ss_c)\.html/(\d+)&([-\w]+)$ $1.php?prometheus_id=$2&id=${products:$3} [L]
# Rewrite other ".html" requests to ".php"
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you expecting the `/public/` URLs to redirect or are you expecting that he `/pl/` URLs show the same content as the `/public/` URLs?

Comment: Is there no last flag (`[L]`) on that rule because you are expecting the html files in the `/public/` directory to get further rewritten from `.html` to `.php`?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller check this `cleoni.com/public/` yes `pl` like `public`

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller All files in `/public/` are rewrite from `php` to `html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "doesn't work" in your example because of *path-info* (additional pathname information) on the originally requested URL. Apache mod_rewrite appends this path-info after the rewrite which *conflicts* with the later rewrite to replace the `.html` extension with `.php`.

When you request `/pl/index.html`, where `/pl` does not exist as a physical directory then the URL-path that follows, ie. `/index.html` is *path-info*. This *path-info* is re-appended after the first rewrite.

For example, given a request for `/pl/index.html`:

1. `RewriteRule ^pl/(.*) public/$1` - this rewrites the request to `public/index.html`.
2. mod_rewrite then appends the *path-info* from the original request to become `public/index.html/index.html`.
3. `RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]` - This directive is now matching against `public/index.html/index.html`, which results in the request being rewritten to `public/index.html/index.php` - which is not the intention and most probably results in a 404 (unless `public/index.html` exists *and* `AcceptPathInfo On` is set).

#### There are three ways you can resolve this, either:

- **Add the `L` flag to the initial `RewriteRule`**:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^pl/(.*) public/$1 [L]
  ```

  This might seem counterintuitive as you still want the later `RewriteRule` to change the file extension - but it still does. The `L` flag does not stop all processing, it only stops the current round of mod_rewrite processing and (in a *directory* context) causes the rewrite engine to start over. Part of the process of "starting over" is that the newly rewritten request is remapped to the file system (and *path-info* is recalculated), so the later `RewriteRule` to replace the `.html` extension is applied to the rewritten URL as expected (since no other rewrites occur in the meantime).

  The rewrite process loops in this way until the URL passes through unchanged. (Or, the `END` flag (Apache 2.4) is encountered.)

OR

- **Add the `DPI` (Discard Path-Info) flag to the initial `RewriteRule`** instead:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^pl/(.*) public/$1 [DPI]
  ```

  This discards the path-info from the current rewrite (and all future rewrites) thus preventing the *path-info* (ie. `/index.html` in this case) from being reappended.

OR

- **Change the *pattern* in the last `RewriteRule`** (that replaces the `.html` file extension) so that it matches the *first* `.html` file extension, and not the *last* file extension. So as to avoid matching against the appended *path-info* (if present). For example:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html $1.php [L]
  ```

  Note the trailing `$` (end-of-string) anchor on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is removed and the captured subpattern is made non-greedy (`.+?`) so as to match the part of the URL-path before the *first* `.html` and not the last `.html`. Any additional *path-info* (if any) - is also discarded by the rewrite.

#### Which method to choose?

Instinctively, I would simply add the `L` flag. However, adding the `DPI` flag instead may in fact be more optimal (it prevents the unnecessary additional loop by the rewrite engine). However, if you add the `DPI` flag I would consider reordering (and grouping) the rules to make it more obvious/readable that it is the intention that the URL could be further rewritten for these requests. (It looks like you would need to apply this same process to two other rules as well?)

The third option to change the *pattern* in the last `RewriteRule` *feels* a bit hacky and I imagine could potentially encounter edge cases that break depending on your URL structure. Although this could still work OK. (Again, reordering of the rules to make the intention more obvious is recommended.)

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^dekoracyjne.html$ decorative.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^techniczne.html$ architectural.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^show.html/([-\w]+)$ show.php?id=${products:$1} [L]
RewriteRule ^p.html$ product_configurator.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^show_c\.html/([-*\w]+)$ show_c.php?cat=${catcolors:$1} [L]
RewriteRule ^(product_configurator)\.html/(\d+)&([-\w]+)$ $1.php?prometheus_id=$2&id=${products:$3} [L]
RewriteRule ^(ss_c)\.html/(\d+)&([-\w]+)$ $1.php?prometheus_id=$2&id=${products:$3} [L]

RewriteRule ^pl/(.*) public/$1 [DPI]
RewriteRule ^dekoracyjne/(.*) decorative/$1 [DPI]
RewriteRule ^techniczne/(.*) architectural/$1 [DPI]

# Rewrite other ".html" requests to ".php"
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

*Aside:* You've included the `NC` flag on two of the rewrites. This naturally makes the initial match case-insensitive - which shouldn't be necessary. If this is required then you potentially have a duplicate content issue, since `foo.html` is strictly different to `FOO.html`.

Comment: I am (as usual) in awe of your knowledge of mod_rewrite's foibles and edge cases.   I'm a bit disturbed that `[L]` doesn't really mean "last."

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks. Yes, the `L` flag is a cause of confusion. However, this is _only_ when used in `.htaccess` (or `<Directory>` containers). When mod_rewrite is used in a _server_ (or vHost) context then `L` does literally mean "last" - and I think this is really what Apache considers the primary use case. Use of mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` does seem somewhat _secondary_, despite this probably being the most common use case. "The rewrite engine may be used in .htaccess files ... with some _additional complexity_."